# Vertical Alignment with using Flex creates horizontal alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using display:flex to vertically align a modal div below:

```
    <div class="row vertical-align">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-0 col-xs-0">
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <img src="images/login-screen.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            Input Fields here
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the css code used.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.modal-dialog {
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 0;
}
.modal-content {
    min-height: 95%;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* works with row or column */
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
}
```

The vertical alignment works great. However, there's a HUGE horizontal alignment too. I just want vertical alignment. What am I missing? I tried the following too:

```
    flex-direction: row;
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want it to look like, but if you use `align-items: stretch;` with `flex-direction: column;` the modal content will stretch to fill the horizontal space.

Comment: Thank you. I did the flex away and use it without flex